# Как делать ассоциативный массив большой вложенности в Java?

Tags: java

Есть у меня массив, примерно такой структуры:

```
array = [
    'charcaters' => [
        'characterName1' => [
            'blockingStance' => [
                ['name' => '1.jpg', 'url' => 'http://site.com/sprites/block/1.jpg'],
                ['name' => '2.jpg', 'url' => 'http://site.com/sprites/block/2.jpg'],
                ['name' => '2.jpg', 'url' => 'http://site.com/sprites/block/3.jpg']
            ],
            'walkingStance' => [
                ['name' => '1.jpg', 'url' => 'http://site.com/sprites/walk/1.jpg'],
                ['name' => '2.jpg', 'url' => 'http://site.com/sprites/walk/2.jpg'],
                ['name' => '2.jpg', 'url' => 'http://site.com/sprites/walk/3.jpg']
            ],
            'specialMoves' => [
                ['name' => '1.jpg', 'url' => 'http://site.com/sprites/special/1.jpg'],
                ['name' => '2.jpg', 'url' => 'http://site.com/sprites/special/2.jpg']
            ],
            ...
        ],
        'characterName2' => [
            .....
        ],
         ...
    ],

    'stages' => [
        'stageName1' => [
            'bridge' => [
                ['name' => '1.jpg', 'url' => 'http://site.com/sprites/bridge/1.jpg'],
                ['name' => '2.jpg', 'url' => 'http://site.com/sprites/bridge/2.jpg'],
                ['name' => '2.jpg', 'url' => 'http://site.com/sprites/bridge/3.jpg']
            ],
            'street' => [
                ['name' => '1.jpg', 'url' => 'http://site.com/sprites/street/1.jpg'],
                ['name' => '2.jpg', 'url' => 'http://site.com/sprites/street/2.jpg'],
                ['name' => '2.jpg', 'url' => 'http://site.com/sprites/street/3.jpg']
            ],
            'forest' => [
                ['name' => '1.jpg', 'url' => 'http://site.com/sprites/forest/1.jpg'],
                ['name' => '2.jpg', 'url' => 'http://site.com/sprites/forest/2.jpg']
            ],
            ...
        ],
        'characterName2' => [
            .....
        ],
         ...
    ],

    'other' => ...

    ......
];
```

Многие любители обкакать *PHP*. Однако там создать такой массив и работать с ним проще простого. И мне кажется это очень удобным.

В Java, исходя из этих данных, у меня итоговый объект является вот таким вот монстром:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<TreeMap<String, String>>>>>
```

где

```
TreeMap<String, String> - это конечные ключ-значение 
ArrayList<TreeMap<String, String>> - список этих самых ключей и значений
Map<String, ArrayList<TreeMap<String, String>>> - ключ: название состояния объекта, значение - список выше.
Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<TreeMap<String, String>>>> - ключ: название объекта, значение - список состояний
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<TreeMap<String, String>>>>> - конечный список.
```

Ужас.

В общем. Может я что-то не так понимаю и делаю, но...

Нет ли в *Java* средств быстро построить ассоциативный массив и желательно неограниченной вложенности?
Возможно ли данную конструкцию с помощью тех средств как-то упростить, чтоб не было такого монстра? Или это is the only way?

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте, юзал JSON и потом парсил бы его

Comment: @AndrewBystrov да, тоже думал об этом. Просто все эти мутированные конструкции для того же парсинга а-ля `obj.getJSONObject("someObject").getJSONArray("characters").get(0).getJSONArray("blockingStance").getJSONArray("name").` вымораживают ))

Comment: Это гораздо лучше чем тип объекта, который Вы написали в вопросе)

Comment: `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<TreeMap<String, String>>>>> ` - так никто не делает. Все что можно выделить в объект выделяется в объект. Это облегчает и написание/чтение кода, и тестирование, и отладку.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Выглядит как попытка натянуть ассоциативный массив там, где он не нужен, так как на самом деле есть четкая структура. А Java любит ООП и классы. По сути у вас есть какие-то коллекции, описывающие последовательности изображений; есть некие персонажи, у которых есть, судя по всему анимации; есть сцены, состоящие из объектов. Это можно представить так:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV682.png]

```
class ImageInfo {
    String name;
    URI url;
}

class Character {
    String name;
    List<ImageInfo> blockingStanceImages;
    List<ImageInfo> walkingStanceImages;
    List<ImageInfo> specialMovesImages;
}

class StageObject {
    String name;
    List<ImageInfo> images;
}

class Stage {
    String name
    Map<String, StageObject> objects;
}

class Context {
    Map<String, Character> characters;
    Map<String, Stage> stages;
}
```