# Модификация конструкции ООП

Tags: java, ооп, java-hashmap

Как можно модифицировать данную конструкцию, используя принципы ООП?

```
Map< Map< String, Map>, List < Map < String, String>>> x = new HashMap();
```

Comment: Для начала напишите, что вы хотите ей сделать. Мап в качестве ключа это нонесенс если честно.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/565554/191482  ммм?

Comment: Заменить мапы на объекты, не?

Comment: @Nofate как дубликат оформить или нет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у того парня неплохой ответ )

Comment: @Saint посмотрите по ссылке во втором комментарии.

Comment: @Nofate я посмотрел Ваш ответ и он мне помог, спасибо)