# Массив VS ArrayList

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist, сравнение

Сделал приложение, в котором собираешь электрические схемы и запускаешь их: из дерева выбираешь элемент, переносишь его, передвигаешь, собираешь схему. Сделано всё это при помощи только массивов.

Программировать начал недавно. Встал вопрос, целесообразно ли переходить на `ArrayList`. Массивы в основном трех- и четырехмерные.

Соответственно, чтобы сделать его через `ArrayList`, необходимо что-то такое:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> arrayList = 
                                 new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    arrayList.add(arrayList2);

    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                row.add(c);
                c++;
            }

        arrayList2.add(row);
        }
}
```

Для объявления массива хватит:

```
String[][][][] VarText = new String[2][20][100][10];
```

Собственно вопрос, плюсы и минусы такого перехода, и хотелось бы узнать у более опытных программистов, через что это обычно делается.

Comment: В вашем случае (с такой вложенностью) нет плюсов.. и надо будет сделать как в ответе тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/565554/191482

Comment: Лучше использовать [Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html). Он позволяет задать initialCapacity чтобы минимизировать перераспределение памяти при добавлении элементов.

Comment: @vp_arth, `ArrayList` позволяет тоже самое

Comment: @iksuy, действительно) Основная разница между ними - синхронизированность методов вектора...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Массивы в java имеют статическую размерность. Поэтому если кол-во элементов, которые необходимо вставить в массив заранее неизвестно - придется пересоздавать массив самостоятельно.

ArrayList - удобная обёртка над массивами, которая ещё и соответсвует интерфейсам collection API. Он, так же оперирует обычными массивами, но позволяет не задумываться о размерностях, поскольку умеет пересоздавать внутри себя массивы, при их заполнении.