# как задать имя массива, включающее значение переменной java?

Tags: java

Создаю я цикл `for(int i =0; i<10; i++)` , в цикле создаю `ArrayList` и мне надо, чтобы в имя `ArrayList` входила переменная `i`. Как это сделать?

Comment: Не надо так делать.

Comment: Какую задачу ты пытаешься так решить?

Comment: У меня есть список стран. Мне надо записать в другой список города, которые находятся в этих странах. Данные брать из базы данных

Comment: Для этого создается класс в Java, который соответствует таблице в БД, с теми же названиями. И заполняется список данного класса... например если класс и таблица `User`, то будет  `ArrayList<User>` в который вынимаются данные..... примерно так: `while (rst.next()) {
        User user= new User(rst.getString("id"), rst.getString("name"), rst.getString("address"), rst.getDouble("email"));
        userList.add(user);
    }` .....В случае произвольного запроса или join'ов - чуть посложнее....но вот таких костылей не надо городить

Comment: точнее мне надо создать многоуровневый список - сначала список стран, страна содержит список городов

Comment: Так, и причем тут динамичесское формирование имя для ArrayList? Глянь...https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/565554/191482.... думаю поймешь смысл. Точнее... смысл не изменился

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так (вместо ... имя типа):

```
Map<String, List<...>> map = new HashMap<>(); 
for(int i =0; i<10; i++) {    
   map.put("имя"+i, new ArrayList<>()); 
}
```

использование `map.get("имя"+i);`